# Regex RDD using Apache Spark Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD:

```
x: Array[String] =
Array("Et: NT=grouptoClassify,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=app_1,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=app_exmpl_2,DB-exec,MDBConnection,NR
group: NT=apprexec,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=nt_prblm_app,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,NR
```

I just want to get the first part of every part of this RDD as you can see in the next example:

```
Et: NT=grouptoClassify
group: NT=app_1
group: NT=app_exmpl_2
group: NT=apprexec
group: NT=nt_prblm_app
```

To do it I am trying it in this way.

```
//Here I get the RDD:
val x = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(value)).collect()
//Try to use regex on it, this regex is to get until the first comma
val regex1 = """(^(.+?),)"""
val rdd_1 = x.map(g => g.matches(regex1))
```

This is what I am trying but is not working for me because I just get an Array of Boolean. What am I doing wrong?

I am new with Apache Spark Scala. If you need something more just tell me it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex :

```
^\s*([^,]+)(_\w+)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BjQhDD/1/)

To implement this regex in your example, you can try :

```
 val arr = Seq("Et: NT=grouptoClassify,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
   "group: NT=app_1,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
   "group: NT=app_exmpl_2,DB-exec,MDBConnection,NR",
   "group: NT=apprexec,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
   "group: NT=nt_prblm_app,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,NR")

val rd_var = spark.sparkContext.parallelize((arr).map((Row(_))))
val pattern = "^\s*([^,]+)(_\w+)?".r

rd_var.map { 
  case Row(str) => str match {
    case pattern(gr1, _) => gr1 
  }
}.foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: If I use regex, i get an array of boolean, how can I get the result?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
val x: Array[String] =
    Array(
      "Et: NT=grouptoClassify,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
      "group: NT=app_1,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
      "group: NT=app_exmpl_2,DB-exec,MDBConnection,NR",
      "group: NT=apprexec,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
      "group: NT=nt_prblm_app,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,NR")

  val rdd = sc.parallelize(x)

  val result = rdd.map(lines => {
    lines.split(",")(0)
  })

  
 result.collect().foreach(println)
```

output:

```
Et: NT=grouptoClassify
group: NT=app_1
group: NT=app_exmpl_2
group: NT=apprexec
group: NT=nt_prblm_app
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in this way I just get the first one (Et: NT=grouptoClassify) :(

Answer (score 0):

With RDD:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

val pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9=:_ ]+),(.*)".r

val el = Seq("Et: NT=grouptoClassify,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
    "group: NT=app_1,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
    "group: NT=app_exmpl_2,DB-exec,MDBConnection,NR",
    "group: NT=apprexec,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready",
    "group: NT=nt_prblm_app,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,NR")


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize((el).map((Row(_))))

   rdd.map {
     case Row(str) => str match {
       case pattern(gr1, _) => gr1
     }
   }.foreach(println(_))

 }
```

It gives:

```
Et: NT=grouptoClassify
group: NT=app_1
group: NT=app_exmpl_2
group: NT=apprexec
group: NT=nt_prblm_app
```

Comment: Looks good but it giving me the output as you can see here: [d], [n], [:], [ ], [C], [N], [=], [g], [r], [p], [_], [i], [n], [t], [e],

Comment: The code above prints the correct result (Spark 2.4.6)

Comment: Ok, it's my bad, the RDD contains just a string. Is an Array of String but all are in a string.

Comment: Then, does it work for you?

Comment: I think so, im testing right now. If i would want to filter first the rows that starts with "group:" Should I use filter and startsWith?

Comment: yes, with RDD you can use every single Scala string-based operation.